# Can I run a front-end and back-end on Netlify?

Tags: netlify

I want to practice creating my own RESTful API service to go along with a client-side application that I've created. My plan is to use Node and Express to create a server. On my local machine, I know how to set up a local server, but I would like to be able to host my application (client and server) online as part of my portfolio.

The data that my client application would send to the server would not be significant in size, so there wouldn't be a need for a database. It would be sufficient to just have my server save received data dynamically in an array, and I wouldn't care about having that data persist if the user exits the webpage.

Is it possible to use a service like Netlify in order to host both a client and server for my purposes? I'm picturing something similar to how I can start up a local dev server on my computer so that the front-end can interface with it. Except now I want everything hosted online for others to view. I plan to create the Express server in the same repo as the front-end code.

Answer (score 7):

No, Netlify doesn't allow you to run a server or backend. However, they do allow you to run serverless functions in the cloud. These can run for up to 10 sec. at a time. Furthermore Netlify also have a BETA solution called "background functions" That can run for up to 15 minutes. But honestly for a RESTful API there sure would be better solutions out there?

Answer (score 2):

If you are still looking for the Netlify for Backend you can consider [Qovery](https://www.qovery.com). They explained [here](https://www.qovery.com/blog/we-built-the-netlify-for-backend-that-runs-on-your-aws-account) why it is a good fit for their users.

Answer (score 1):

Netlify has [Functions](https://www.netlify.com/products/#netlify-edge-functions) similar to AWS Lambda functions, which are designed for writing, for example, an API endpoint.

Comment: Functions are just Lambas. At least up until a few years ago, Netlify was virtually a DX front for AWS.